# Font awesome icons missing randomly

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

Noticing that sometimes font awesome icons disappear in `v5.6` with following Rendered Fonts pointing to Local `Arial Black` glyph randomly. For following icon with style

```
<i className="fal fa-chevron-down fas"/> 

.fa-chevron-down:before {
    content: "\F078";
}
```

[image: Fa missing fonts]

The only way to get icon displayed after this happens is to to disable `font-weight: 900` from below style to get it displayed.

```
.fa, .fas {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

When it does display the icon correctly, it shows the `Rendered Font` correctly as `Font Awesome 5 Pro Solid—Network resource(1 glyph)`

Why does this happen?

Comment: in font awesome, font-weight shows type of font like regular solid pro

Comment: Ok, how does it render Arial Black as font instead of Font Awesome 5 even though it being shown as computed font family?